# Why webpack keep download in Next.js app?

Tags: webpack, next.js, infinite-loop

[image]

```js
function BuyTicket(props: BuyTicketProps) {
  const {
    eventId,
    buyTicketDataBE,
    sortedBookings,
    recommendations,
    sortedEventTimes,
    couponRedeemString,
    translations,
    lang,
  } = props;
  const [buyTicketData, setBuyTicketData] = useState({ ...buyTicketDataBE });
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    setBuyTicketData({ ...buyTicketDataBE });
  }, [buyTicketDataBE]);

useEffect(() => {
  // ..
  }, []);
```

I put in many console.log(), but none of them is called repeatedly. Strange.

Comment: Is that a dev or production build?

Comment: dev build, why? is it any difference?

Comment: Yes, it's webpack's [hot module replacement](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/) feature, basicly [fest refresh](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/fast-refresh). This will not occur in a production build.